# iOS Wifi Camera Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, wifi, ip-camera

I have a wifi camera I want to connect to, [https://www.amazon.com/Wireless-Endoscope-WIFI-Magic-Smartphone/dp/B074PN9DB4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074PN9DB4)

I have tried using a Lib called https://github.com/alchimya/iOS-IPCamViewer which works with other wifi cameras but not this box.

The iPhone is connected to the devices wifi and it works using the demo app https://itunes.apple.com/za/app/f100/id1214909934?mt=8.

So I know it works.

However how do I connect this this device in objective c ?

What I have done so far:

```
L3SDKIPCam*ipCam1=[[L3SDKIPCam alloc]init];
ipCam1.url=[self getIPAddress];
ipCam1.videoFolder=@"axis-cgi/mjpg/";
ipCam1.videoName=@"video.cgi";
ipCam1.password = @"pw";
ipCam1.username = @"user";
```

I have allowed for Http loads in my plist
but this is the error i am getting:

```
Printing description of ((__NSDictionaryI *)0x00000001d40ef780):
{
  NSErrorFailingURLKey = "http://192.168.10.20:80/axis-cgi/mjpg//video.cgi?(null)";
  NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "http://192.168.10.20:80/axis-cgi/mjpg//video.cgi?(null)";
  NSLocalizedDescription = "Could not connect to the server.";
  NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 \"Could not connect to the server.\" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.10.20:80/axis-cgi/mjpg//video.cgi?(null), NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.10.20:80/axis-cgi/mjpg//video.cgi?(null), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1,     NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}";
"_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey" = 61;
"_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey" = 1;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: "Could not connect to the server" usually comes if the IP/Port combination is not reachable or not running the HTTP service.

Comment: Hello, have you find any solution to connect endoscope with this SDK. I am facing the same issue please share the solution.